# How can I exclude one html view in whole project to be applied from CSS?

Tags: html, css, angularjs, visual-studio-2012, devextreme

I am working on Cross Platform application on DevExtreme. It includes 8-10 number of CSS files to be applied on my project for all the html views. CSS are having so many background-color:,background: properties set according to the theme(ios platform/android/win8 etc), 
which creates different layers in application html views.

But I want to create a html view in my project to be excluded from all these CSS and to make its background as TRANSPARENT.

How can I exclude one html view among many, where I can apply on selected CSS rather than all CSS linked in my inde.xml file ?

I hope my question is clear to understand. Please help. Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried creating a specific CSS class to apply to this one view with a background set as transparent?

Comment: Actually, I am using this <div class="view-content" dx-scroll-view>. This view-content class is in 12  CSS files, dx-theme-ios,dx-theme-android etc. In worst case only I can delete it.
And there are 2 css: index.css and app.css to be applied to all views including my view, in these 2 css I m making background-color: transparent but still its not transparent.

Comment: @Muggles I tried to do it but still its not making my background as transparent, even its not showing my body tag color as !important. But I think other css are conflicting with this.

Answer (score 1):

If your HTML is inheriting CSS files from index.xml file then its not possible to exclude from getting css applied to it. but on other hand you can add extra class to overwrite all the properties which are getting applied to your HTML snipet.

**for Eg.**

```
.myhtml{
  background: transparent !important;
}
```

there are different techniques of overwriting inherited css properties and for that you need to understand how css is getting applied on the basis of number of selectors in the rule.
here is more description: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started/Selectors

**Also please check**

**CSS Specificity Examples**

First count the element names. This can be either HTML elements or XML elements. For ease of distinguishing them, I will write them in all-caps.

```
* { ... } = 0 
P { ... } = 1 
DIV P { ... } = 2 
H3 + P { ... } = 2
```

Count classes, pseudo-classes and non-ID attributes and multiply by 10.

```
.top { ... } = 10 
P.top { ... } = 11 
a:link { ... } = 11 
a.new:link { ... } = 21 
H3.bottom + p.top { ... } = 22 
DIV + *[title] { ... } = 11
```

IDs are the most specific, so count them and multiply by 100.

```
#a1 { ... } = 100 
#a1.red { ... } = 110 
H3#a1.red { ... } = 111 
blockquote #a2 { ... } = 101
```

Comment: It sounds good, I will try to apply it and will be back with consequences. Can you please tell me, Do CSS files get applied to view in the proper sequence as they are linked in index.html file ??

Comment: Yes, CSS files get applied to view in the proper sequence as they are linked in index.html file. but there are some possibilities in which the sequence of CSS rules getting applied may alter. for eg.

Comment: If I am replacing all the background-color: .*; with background-color: transparent; in entire solution then only it displays as transparent. But it will ruin theme effect.

When I am writing  background: transparent !important; in my last 2 css linked in index.html without ruining theme effect, it isn't make it transparent. !

Comment: **I want to make body tag's background as transparent.** In AngularJS, body tag is there in index.html only and from there all the views are rendered. 
And all the css access body tag in styles, I want to overwrite it.
I referred that link of Id,Class,Pseudo class and their priorities too. But I am not getting how to apply it to body tag. Please help.

Comment: Can you provide a url ? so I can checkout the possibilities?

Comment: I applied transparent style on body tag, but there are so many CSS which are getting applied in my application.
I opened my camera activity in new HTML page and overwrote all CSS classes which creates its background layer in my camera activity page. And it solved my problem.
Thank you so much for your responses.