# Customize jQuery dialog close button

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I have many jQuery-ui dialogs in my application and I am trying to customize the close button of dialog, as in I am trying to remove some default classes, trying to remove the hover class (`ui-state-hover`) and also trying to remove the auto focus feature.

Currently, I have added the below code to achieve the same in `open` option of dialog function:-

```
$('button[title="close"].ui-dialog-titlebar-close')
    .removeClass("ui-button-icon-only ui-state-default ui-button ui-widget")
    .hover(function () { $(this).removeClass("ui-state-hover"); })
    .blur()
    .css({ "border": "none" });
```

Although, this was my last option after trying all day because it seems pretty ugly to me. I have also tried overwriting the default hover & focus classes in my custom CSS file like this:-

```
.ui-state-hover { background: none!important; border:none!important;}
.ui-state-focus { outline-color: transparent !important; }
```

I have made sure that my custom CSS appears after `jQuery-ui.css` file but still no luck. Is there any better way to do this? I want to do this for all the dialogs in my application.

Comment: Can you please updated your code in fiddle.

Comment: Sorry @stanze but I don't have access to JSFiddle now. I can't update there.

Answer (score 1):

to change hover and focus state CSS you will need to overwrite the entire rule as follows

CSS

```
.ui-state-hover,
.ui-widget-content .ui-state-hover,
.ui-widget-header .ui-state-hover,
.ui-state-focus,
.ui-widget-content .ui-state-focus,
.ui-widget-header .ui-state-focus {
  background: none!important; 
  border:none!important;
  outline:none!important;
}
```

**Edited:**

to refer how exactly css are getting applied please refer my answer in this post:  [How can I exclude one html view in whole project to be applied from CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29768666/how-can-i-exclude-one-html-view-in-whole-project-to-be-applied-from-css/29769190#29769190)

Comment: Can you check in browser developer option, that which css rule is getting applied?

Comment: Which rule is getting applied? the one from jquery.css file or the one from custom.css file?

Comment: Rule from Custom.css.

Comment: can you share url or fiddle? or something else? I can not figure out your problem now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75897/discussion-between-nilesh-mahajan-and-rahul-singh).

Comment: I don't have access to Fiddle currently so I can't show what I is happening exactly. But thanks for your help, my workaround in working fine now.

Comment: This worked for me, I just had to add .ui-dialog before class.  i.e. *.ui-dialog* .ui-state-hover,
.ui-widget-content .ui-state-hover,
.ui-widget-header .ui-state-hover,
.ui-state-focus,
.ui-widget-content .ui-state-focus,
.ui-widget-header .ui-state-focus {
  background: none!important; 
  border:none!important;
  outline:none!important;
}